# Multi-source multi-sink multi-waypoint group shortest path

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to tackle the following graph theoretical problem:

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with weighted edges, multiple sources $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k$, multiple sinks $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_l$ and multiple sets of vertices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m$, where no vertex is in two sets and there can also be vertices that are in none of the sets, find the shortest path between one of the sources to one of the sinks that passes through exactly one vertex of each of the $A_i$ sets. The path can pass through vertices that are not part of any of the groups.

I have been trying to find literature on this problem but I have two issues:

1. Is there a proper naming to this problem? I know it is a variation of the multi-source multi-sink shortest path problem but is there any proper designation for passing through one vertex from a set?
2. Are there any published materials on this problem, a similar problem or a simplified version? Total enumeration of all the possible combinations would work for a small graph but my application requires a very large number of sources, sinks and vertices in each group so the amount of possible combinations is too high.